# What is Api level testing for developers?

Tags: unit-testing

I didnt get any information while searching through the google for developers But tester side we can able to get the information.But i nee d to know for the developers . How to do that ?

Can someone help me how to get through it

Comment: When I google "api level testing" I find useful information. You should provide more information.

Comment: yah i found information but  related to tester.I need information for the developers . how  should to do that etc ...,

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make a couple of assumptions in your question. Please comment if any are incorrect:

1. Your product has a user interface (e.g. Web UI) that interacts via a defined API with the backend.
2. You are working on the backend part of the product.
3. You have a QA/test team (or QA/test engineers within your team).
4. As a developer you want to the test the API to catch regressions early.
5. You don't want to overlap / step on the toes of the QA/test team.

If all of my assumptions are correct then great, you are thinking about this the right way. You want to hand over quality code to the people testing your work.

Now on to your question `What is API level testing for developers?` I am going to simply say that API level testing can be one of the following:

1. Functional testing [Testing Types](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/the-difference-between-unit-integration-and-functional-testing/) when you consider the backend as the system you are testing.
2. Integration testing when you consider the backend and the UI to as the system you are testing.

From here you can start thinking about what testing the developer should do before the API is handed over to the test team. This is going to vary from organisation to organisation. So my advice, talk to the test team and find out what they expect from the developers. This way you can ensure that testing isn't falling through the cracks between the teams and the overlap is minimal so the whole engineering team are as efficient as possible.

If you would like me to expand on the answer, then please add some more detail to the question.

Comment: can you explain  me what kind of test is this ?

def test_something(client):
     resp = client.get(url)
     assert (resp.status_code == 200)

Comment: That depends on where the response is coming from. If the response is coming from a 'real' web server then I would call it an integration test. Because it is testing the integration between the web server and the client.

Comment: If the reply is coming from a mock of the Web Server then I would call it a unit test because it is testing the code of the client and nothing else. Hope this helps.